# What does it mean to project a vector onto a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not quite sure what is meant by projecting a vector onto a line in linear algebra.

In this video [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts3o2I8_Mxc&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8&index=32) (34:45), the lecturer draws a line on which the vectors will be projected on. One vector when transformed stays on the line while the other vector becomes zero. I thought that "projecting" would mean all vectors would go underneath the line.

How do you project those two vectors?

Comment: You are basically taking the component of that vector along the line. Hence the vector will be $({\vec a}{\cdot}{\hat n}){\hat n}$.

Comment: Suppose, there's a sun just one the tip of vector `u`. Then the shadow falling on vector `v` is the projection of `u` on `v`.

Answer (score 1):

If we move from the end of vector $\mathbb u$ in a direction that is perpendicular to $\mathbb v$ until we intersect $\mathbb v$ we have found the projection of $\mathbb u$ onto $\mathbb v$

[image]

The projection will be in the direction of $\mathbb v$ and be of a magnitude equal to $\mathbb u\cos \theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbb u$ and $\mathbb v$

A direct calculation is $\frac {\mathbb u\cdot \mathbb v}{\|\mathbb v\|^2} \mathbb v$